# Android show call screen( using fullScreenIntent) without head-up state

Tags: android, android-intent, fullscreen

I want to implement call function when user were not open my app, by calling showFullScreenIntent function

It works fine when screen is locked, mean the incoming screen were show. But when device is not locked, the call is display only in head-up state. So I want to show full incoming screen, does anyone face this problem? Thanks

I updated code to show fullScreenIntent below:

```
private fun sendFullScreenCall(callInfoModel: CallInfoModel) {
        val icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher)

        val showingCallScreenIntent = Intent(applicationContext, CallingScreen::class.java)
        showingCallScreenIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        showingCallScreenIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        showingCallScreenIntent.action = "Accept"
        showingCallScreenIntent.putExtra("callObj", callInfoModel)
        showingCallScreenIntent.putExtra(STATE, INCOMING)

        val acceptIntent = Intent(applicationContext, SingleCallScreen::class.java)
        acceptIntent.putExtra("callObj", callInfoModel)

        val showingCallScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, showingCallScreenIntent , PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
        val acceptCallPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, acceptIntent , PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
        val dimissCallPendingIntent = DismissCallKolinActivity.getDismissIntent(Random().nextInt(), this@FirebaseMessagingService, callInfoModel)
        val soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + applicationContext.packageName + "/" + R.raw.rongtone_incoming)
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Incoming call")
            .setContentText(callInfoModel.CallerDisplay)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_video_enabled, getActionText("Answer", R.color.green_color), acceptCallPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_clear, getActionText("Dismiss", R.color.red), dimissCallPendingIntent)
            .setFullScreenIntent(showingCallScreenPendingIntent, true)
            .setContentIntent(showingCallScreenPendingIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID)?.let {
                notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(it.id)
            }
        }
        NotificationUtils.createChannel(this@FirebaseMessagingService, notificationManager)
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, 1, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also set category: 
`setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)`

Also, if your app targets Android 10 or higher, you need to request the `USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT` permission in order for the platform to invoke this notification: 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />`

Comment: still show headup when "app running + i press homebutton"  -> fullscreenintent show as head-up